# Add time between 2 dates across multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that lists all users for my company. There are multiple entries for each staff member showing how they have been employed.

```
RowID   UserID  FirstName   LastName    Title      StartDate    Active  EndDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       John        Smith       Manager    2017-01-01   0       2017-01-31 
2       1       John        Smith       Director   2017-02-01   0       2017-02-28 
3       1       John        Smith       CEO        2017-03-01   1       NULL
4       2       Sam         Davey       Manager    2017-01-01   0       2017-02-28 
5       2       Sam         Davey       Manager    2017-03-01   0       NULL
6       3       Hugh        Holland     Admin      2017-02-01   1       NULL
7       4       David       Smith       Admin      2017-01-01   0       2017-02-28
```

I am trying to write a query that will tell me someones length of service at any given time.

The part I am having trouble with is as a single person is represented by multiple rows as their information changes over time I need combine multiple rows...

I have a query to report on who is employed at a point in time which is as far as I have gotten.

```
DECLARE @DateCheck datetime 
SET @DateCheck = '2017/05/10'

SELECT * 
FROM UsersTest
WHERE @DateCheck >= StartDate AND @DateCheck <= ISNULL(EndDate, @DateCheck)
```

Comment: The real challenge here is because your data is not normalized. You should have an employee table with a column for hire date. Then in a separate table you have their history. Something like EmployeePosition that would have start and end dates for that position. Consider how horrible this design is when a person changes their name.

Comment: I asked a separate question around this a while back as the best way to sort it out. If it helps ignore all columns except RowID, UserID, StartDate and EndDate. The idea will to only ever return the information for the record that is current as per the date value supplied.

Comment: Hopefully somebody pointed out the design flaw with your normalization in your last question. The reason you are having a hard time with your query is because your architecture is flawed. If this was properly normalized the query would be super simple.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Comment: That was were I was directed. I used typed 2.

Comment: I was not getting that was a DW. In this case just use the query that Adam Jacobson posted below.

Comment: Thanks, Have been working with it now getting my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the datediff function. The key will be choosing the appropriate number - days, months, years. The return value is an integer so if you choose years, it will be rounded (and remember, it will round for each record, not for the summary. I've chosen months below.   The following has been added to get the most recent information for user name:

```
WITH CurrentName AS
  (SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName 
     from
     UserStartStop
     where Active = 1 -- You can replace this with a date check
  ) 

SELECT uss.UserID, 
   MAX(cn.FirstName) as FirstName, -- the max is necessary because we are
                                   -- grouping.  Could include in group by   
   MAX(cn.LastName) as LastName,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(mm,uss.StartDate,COALESCE(uss.EndDate,GETDATE())))
   from UserStartStop uss
   JOIN CurrentName cn
     on uss.UserID = cn.UserID
GROUP BY UserID
order by UserID
```

Comment: DateDiff doesn't round. It counts the number of date thresholds crossed between two dates. The query will do what they want but the explanation isn't quite correct.

Comment: I misspoke and realized afterwords.  In any case, I realized that with either explanation, i should have used days and then divided by 365 to get to years.   Using Months introduces too many rounding errors

Comment: Thanks! How do I ensure that I am always returning the most current row with respect to the date? I changed GETDATE() to be @DateCheck and changed mm to DD.

Comment: Again, it doesn't do any rounding at all. It simply counts the thresholds crossed. For example select datediff(year, '2016-12-31', '2017-01-01') returns 1. If you rounded that it would be 0.

Comment: Sorry.  the point is by choosing days and then summing those, I'll get a more accurate answer

Comment: I don't understand the question about the most current row

Comment: When I return the title for example. How do I ensure that I am returning to current title for the correct date with your query above? Wont MAX simply return the one that is highest numerically vs the one I need? Or Should I simply return the RowID and the DateDiff into a temp table and then update that temp table with the corresponding info?

Comment: You don't need a temp table.  You can create a CTE which selects names for the currently active record and then join the CTE to the query I wrote.   Writing to a temp table is not required.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what that is. If you have time to show an example that would be great. If not ill continue to google it. Thanks!

Comment: I've made the change above.  Learning about CTE's changed my life.  Which is either a comment on the value of CTE's or the state of my life.

Comment: Mate, I love you. For the help and that last line got me good. Solid 5 minutes of constant laughing.

Comment: If there were only a badge for comedy.  Oh well. I'll keep my day job

Comment: but seriously, Steve Stedman has good stuff on CTE's.  You can start here: http://stevestedman.com/2015/02/what-is-a-common-table-expression/

Answer (score 1):

For months in service, change 'd' to 'mm':

```
Create table #UsersTest (
      RowId int
    , UserID int
    , FirstName nvarchar(100)
    , LastName nvarchar(100)
    , Title nvarchar(100)
    , StartDate date
    , Active bit
    , EndDate date)

Insert #UsersTest values (1, 1, 'John', 'Smith', 'Manager', '2017-01-01', 0, '2017-01-31')
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 1, 'John', 'Smith', 'Director', '2017-02-01', 0, '2017-02-28')
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 1, 'John', 'Smith', 'CEO', '2017-03-01', 1, null)
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 2, 'Sam', 'Davey', 'Manager', '2017-01-01', 0, '2017-02-28')
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 2, 'Sam', 'Davey', 'Manager', '2017-03-01', 0, null)
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 3, 'Hugh', 'Holland', 'Admin', '2017-02-01', 1, null)
Insert #UsersTest values (1, 4, 'David', 'Smith', 'Admin', '2017-01-01', 0, '2017-02-28')

Declare @DateCheck as datetime = '2017/05/10'
Select UserID, FirstName, LastName
    , Datediff(d, Min([StartDate]), iif(isnull(Max([EndDate]),'1900-01-01')<@DateCheck, @DateCheck ,Max([Enddate]))) as [LengthOfService]
from #UsersTest
Group by UserID, FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: I had to change DateCheck to @DateCheck and I assume Maxdate is meant to be EndDate? That being the case. I get a correct answer for UserID 3, All others show as 129 days..

Comment: @Zac I have made changes to include those corrections.

Answer (score -2):

Try it's

```
   Select 
FirstName, 
LastName,
Min(StartDate)StartDate,
Max(isnull(EndDate,getdate()) as EndDate
    from Table
```

Comment: This won't work because you have no Group By clause here.